# How to query Google Cloud for not exceeding the free quota of a service?

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-text-to-speech, google-cloud-monitoring, google-cloud-php-client

I'm actually coding a tool for text to speech language learning and use the Google Cloud Text-to-Speech API.
There is a free quota of 1 and 4 million bytes per month.

Does anybody know how to query the used bytes per type and month?
I couldn't find the right docs for this. If I knew the correct request,
I can look which PHP Client Lib I have to use for this.

I tested the Billing API, but there are different types of information.
Maybe the Monitoring API is the right one, but it's the first time ever I use google cloud, so I'm totally overwhelmed at the moment ‍

kr
basti

I tried https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/reference/rest/ Requests but it seems to be something totally different.

I need a request for information like "you have used 25000 bytes of 4000000 bytes of standard voice synthesis".

Comment: Therefore I think the monitoring API maybe can deliver how many Bytes are used this month.

Comment: Review this link from Operations Suite: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-quota-metrics Check if there is a metric for your use case: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/browsing-metrics#res-list-basic